# Removal of dynamically generated ads

Tags: tags, nodes, ads, userscripts

I have a question regarding some not typical tags used on many web sites to make harder to remove the ads with adblocker extensions.

The most commonly used ones are (given as example):

```
 * <dd-handler slot="sometext">
 * <nh-something (...)> (for example: <nh-topbar>)
```

Under them is a generated content with dynamically assigned either class, id or other not standard attribute.

I would like to write a user script, with would remove such nodes (with their dynamical content). Any idea how should I start?

I tryed to use `getElementByTag()` and other ones, but it didn't helped too much.

Comment: I share your frustration, but on Stackoverflow you're generally expected to first try to write some code and then ask a question when it fails. Try to consider analysing the path to the node in the document or detecting it by the contents and dimensions (image, wide, etc).

Comment: I wanted to share the code, but to do that, I need to write it first. Unfortunately, I don't know to select such things from the html to get it removed